# sending mail with the use of asterisk voicemail

Tags: python-2.7, asterisk

I am using asterisk and via extensions.conf I have to send voicemail to mail by using python script.
Python script is running fine but I don't have idea how to use that with extensions.
SMTP code is working fine.

context are below-

```
import smtplib 
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText 
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase 
from email import encoders

fromaddr = "from"
toaddr = "to"
```

Comment: Asterisk have internal voicemail system. Also it have ability send voicemail via external sendmail-like script. See voicemail.conf.sample

Comment: i know about voicemail.conf but do not want to use that thats why i am looking for another option

Comment: If so, you have read much more about asterisk and scripting.

Comment: already use voicemail.conf and its working

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments in your questions, seems you already have it working with Asterisk built-in, so you should have a valid reason to process outside, being this the case, maybe you could use Asterisk System application to call the script from the dialplan or externnotify in voicemail.conf to call the Python script which will receive (*need to test*) as parameters: context, extension, new voicemails, old voicemails, urgent voicemails.